# Angular - How do I hide a popup after few seconds?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

How to hide popup message after few seconds in Angular 2 through RX store?

Here is the code which I am working on:

```
case ECMTOOL_RUN_SAVE_SUCCESS:
  return Object.assign({},state,{
    isSaveComplete: true,
    blockForm:false,
    saveResponse: action.payload,
    msgs: [{severity:'success', summary:'Message', detail:'Model saved'}]
  });
```

Message "Model Saved' should disappear after few seconds...

Comment: What is RX store? Can you provide a link or more information? or maybe more code to give this some context? Typically, you would use a timeout function that changes some property after n number of seconds, but its tough to know how you could apply that here without aditional context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascripts `setTimeout()`.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    hidePopup = true; //change the *ngIf variable here
}, 1000); //1000 equals the time in miliseconds
```